# Go HTTP service implemented with Gin sends about 50% of the data then closes the connection, why?

Tags: web-services, http, go, connection

I have an HTTP service which sends very large files to the client (most often between 50Mb and 100Mb). When I start several clients in parallel, I often get part of the file (500Kb to 25Mb) and then the server closes the connection.

If I'm the only one to do a `GET` with a single connection, it doesn't close the connection until the entire file was transferred. So the service works when not under load.

Here is how my Gin handler looks like:

```
func handler(c *gin.Context) {
    ...some initialization...

    // prepare list of readers
    readers := []io.Reader{}
    size := 0

    ...load some data in a []byte buffer...

    // create one reader and stack it in `readers`
    readers = append(readers, bytes.NewReader(data))
    size += len(data)

    ...repeat as needed for this request...

    // create stream
    r := io.MultiReader(readers...)

    // send data
    c.Status(http.StatusOK)  // HTTP 200 response
    c.Header("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(size, 10))
    io.CopyN(c.Writer, audioReader, size)
}
```

As I mentioned, the process works just fine when I do one `GET` at a time and wait for completion.

When I run two or more `GET` in parallel, that's when things break.

I'm wondering whether the Gin TCP connection gets reused and thus the `io.CopyN()` get interrupted before it completed. If so, how would I wait to make sure `io.CopyN()` is done?!

I know a `close()` is possible if I'm directly in control of the socket, but that doesn't work well if the HTTP protocol said `keep-alive` but especially, closing on my end, I may be walking on Gin's toes. I have some integration tests which send/receive hundreds of connections and transfers Mb of data and these work great. Only I don't ever send two requests in parallel in those tests (at least not yet).

Comment: You seem to be loading all the data in memory, and then sending it. Maybe you're running out of memory when processing multiple requests this way.

Comment: @bserdar, We have 150Gb or RAM or so. So 10 to 100 requests won't kill the service because of memory. Also the service doesn't restart which I would imagine it would in your scenario.

Comment: You don't show how `sendSize` is calculated.  Is it possible that it's incorrect?  Why does the application use io.CopyN instead of io.Copy?  It might be a concurrency error given that the problem only happens when there are concurrent requests. Run the application with the [race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector).

Comment: Sorry, I have support for `Range: ...` as well so the `sendSize` may be smaller whan a `Range: ...` request happen. However, I can see the size as I also stick it in `Content-Length: ...` (added to example above). So it is correct. This is also why I use `CopyN()` instead of `Copy()`. Note that at this time I've not tested `Range: ...` at all. I send "plain" `GET` requests. As I mentioned, since it works when I send just one single request, I'm confident that the logic is correct.

Comment: The code posted in the most recent edit looks good.  The problem is in code that we cannot see (it's either code in the ... or the actual code is different from what's posted here).